# Ошибка при подключении libsasl.dll

Tags: c++

Всем привет!

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться со следующим:
Установил библиотеку cURL, раскидав либы и длл файлы по нужным папкам. Скачал libsasl.dll, закинув в систем32. Пытаюсь откомпилировать, пишет: “точка входа в процедуру sasl_errdetail не найдена в библиотеке DLL libsasl.dll”.
Как победить проблему? Может у кого есть эта ДЛЛ-ка (целая) или может дело совсем не в этом, так как уже 2 раза скачивал с разных ресурсов эту библиотеку – результат один и тот же…

Comment: Для начала посмотреть тем же Вузуdency Walker есть ли sasl_errdetail в этой dll.

Comment: Победил! Обновил ДЛЛ-ку и заработало. А что за Вузуdency Walker?